# create a new variable in the data frame based on multiple criteria in r

Tags: r, multidplyr

I have a data set which has

```
COl1 COl2 Col3   
1     0     0 
0     1     0
0     0     1 
1     0     0
```

Based on these three column i need to add new variable in the same table

Expected Output

```
COl1 COl2 Col3  New_variable   
1     0     0     c1
0     1     0     c2
0     0     1     c3
1     0     0     c1
```

Answer (score 3):

If we want to assign variable based on presence of 1 in each row we can use `max.col`.

```
df$New_variable <- paste0('c', max.col(df))
df
#  COl1 COl2 Col3 New_variable
#1    1    0    0           c1
#2    0    1    0           c2
#3    0    0    1           c3
#4    1    0    0           c1
```

In case of multiple 1's in a row check various `ties.method` in `?max.col`.

---

If we need to assign unique ID to each row based we can row-wise paste the values and then use `match` to assign ID.

```
vals <- do.call(paste, c(df, sep = "-"))
df$New_variable <- paste0('c', match(vals, unique(vals)))
```

Comment: liked your `max.col` method

Answer (score 0):

Here are some base R solutions:

```
df$New_variable <- paste0("c",seq(df)%*%t(df))
```

or

```
df$New_variable <- paste0("c",rowSums(df*col(df)))
```

or

```
df$New_variable <- paste0("c",which(t(df)==1,arr.ind = T)[,"row"])
```

such that

```
> df
  COl1 COl2 Col3 New_variable
1    1    0    0           c1
2    0    1    0           c2
3    0    0    1           c3
4    1    0    0           c1
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(COl1 = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), COl2 = c(0L, 1L, 0L, 
0L), Col3 = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 0L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Comment: @ThomaslsCoding Thank you it works nicely but i have 30 columns and want specific columns to be  used liked that . can i have any update code for the data set

Comment: @king_arrival27 sorry that I don't understand "want specific columns to be used liked that . can i have any update code for the data set ". Can you provide some example for what you described?

Answer (score 0):

Another `base` option:

```
df$New_variable <- paste0('c', apply(df, 1, function(x) which(x != 0)))
```

Output:

```
  COl1 COl2 Col3 New_variable
1    1    0    0           c1
2    0    1    0           c2
3    0    0    1           c3
4    1    0    0           c1
```

Since there is a vague reference to `dplyr` in tags, you could also use this in combination with `purrr` - though it is clearly an overkill compared to variety of `base` solutions available (as evident from all the answers):

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    New_variable = purrr::pmap(select(., 1:3), ~ paste0('c', which(c(...) != 0)))
    )
```

Whereby in the `select(., 1:3)` statement you can choose which columns to use (here we use all 3 columns, so you could just use `.` instead of the whole `select` and it would have the same effect).